# renderer.material.color giving strange results

Tags: colors, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a weird problem, that i can't figure out. 
I want to change a gameobjects base color via renderer.material.color.
But for whatever reason, this only works for some colors.

This is my code:

first, I declare the colors:

```
    var color_movement_available = Color(0.17,0.68,0.05,1);
    var color_movement_available_hover = Color(0.33,1.00,0.17,1);
```

then i assign them, like this

```
    case ("movement_available") : 
       renderer.material.color = color_movement_available; 
       break;

    case ("movement_available_hover") : 
       renderer.material.color = color_movement_available_hover;
       break;
```

However, when I test the script, the hovering color (pinkish) will not show.
I checked in the inspector and the color is the one i aimed for and is correctly switched. 
When i change it to a bright (basecolor) green, red, blue or yellow, it works as supposed.
Other colors will produce white and some wont change anything.

**Has anyone an idea what's causing this effect, or better yet, how to solve it?**

What i tried so far:

- switching the material renderer to diffuse (from transparent/diffuse):
  same results
- changing the materials initial basecolor to grey (from white):
  also, no change

Maybe this has something to do with the way colors are applied ...

cheers

Edit: Screenshots:
[image: Visual clarification 1]

Also, apparently, colors that are close to each other, like the same color only darker/lighter appear to be the ones producing white

Comment: edited origanal post with screencap

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have a mesh renderer on your object.

Try GetComponent< MeshRenderer >().material.color

Comment: The editor refused `GetComponent< MeshRenderer >().material.color`, so i went with `GetComponent( MeshRenderer ).material.color`. Didnt make any difference, though. I guess since the meshrenderer is the only one on this object, `renderer.material.color` returns the same as `GetComponent< MeshRenderer >().material.color`...